# Xpath returns null Web Scraping

Tags: c#, html, xpath, linq-to-xml

I am performing web scraping and I have tried all possible combinations but XPath is returning `null` value.

I have removed square brackets and have added `//` for it but it returns `null` each time.
These are the actual XPath and I have attached the formatted one that I am using in my code.

```
//*[@id="agent_list_wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a
//*[@id="agent_list_wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]
```

Below is my code.

```
private async Task<List<NameAndphone>> WebDateFromPage(int pagenum)
{
    string url = "http://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/New-York_NY/photo-1";

    if (pagenum != 0)
        url = "http://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/New-York_NY/photo-1/pg-" + pagenum.ToString();

    var doc = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => web.Load(url));
    var name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"agent_list_wrapper\"]//div//div//div/div//a");
    var phone = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"agent_list_wrapper\"]//div//div//div//div");
    if (name == null || phone == null)
        return new List<NameAndPhone>();

    var names = name.Select(node => node.InnerText);
    var phones = phone.Select(node => node.InnerText);

    return names.Zip(phones, (name, phone) => new NameAndPhone() { Name = name, Phone = phone }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can confirm that the xpath actually exists in the XML file?  Can you posta snippet the XML document?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly do you want.. I am new to this, and i do not have much idea about this i would be extremely thankful if you can help me in this regard

Comment: I have edited my code i am trying to get the name and phone numbers from attached website

Comment: I am not sure how to read xml structure. Can you please guide me a bit?

Comment: I am getting the complete website content when i hover my mouse over and check the value in text field.

Comment: Very strange... "//a" and "//div" should return something for pretty much any HTML document. Please [edit] post and provide [MCVE].

Comment: @GiladGreen Do you want me to post it completely here.. It is a complete HTML file and quite big.

Comment: @FaranSaleem - Got it using the address you added in your code. See answer below.

Comment: Bear in mind that explicit requests for urgency are discouraged here, and may result in downvotes. Our advice is not to add such phrases to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved using below code

Thanks

```
string url_base=@"http://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/New-York_NY/photo-1/pg-";
function GetPageContent(int page_no)
{
   return new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url_base+page_no);
}
var file_path=@"C:\Dump\Data.xml";

var content=GetPageContent(1);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file_path,content);


HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
doc.Load(file_path);

var name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"agent_list_wrapper\"]//div//div//div/div//a");
var phone = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"agent_list_wrapper\"]//div//div//div//div");


var names = name.Select(node => node.InnerText);
var phones = phone.Select(node => node.InnerText);

var result = names.Zip(phones, (n, p) => new { Name = n, Phone = p }).ToList();
//Result has 58 items
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your `XPATH` is working fine (though the data itself needs some cleaning). Used this code to test:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
doc.Load("data.xml");

var name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"agent_list_wrapper\"]//div//div//div/div//a");
var phone = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"agent_list_wrapper\"]//div//div//div//div");


var names = name.Select(node => node.InnerText);
var phones = phone.Select(node => node.InnerText);

var result = names.Zip(phones, (n, p) => new { Name = n, Phone = p }).ToList();
//Result has 58 items
```

*Used this url for test data: `http://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/New-York_NY/photo-1/pg-1`*

[image]

---

I would recommend that you re-think your XPATH because it is so specific and depends on the structure. Try use the attributes of: `itemprop="name"` and `itemprop="telephone"` - less likely to change if they change the layout of their website